# Delete duplicates between groups in R

Tags: r

Thanks in advance for any help.
my Data looks like this:

```
|year|class|
|---|----|
|2007|a|
|2007|b|
|2007|c|
|2007|d|
|2008|a|
|2008|b|
|2008|e|
|2008|f|
|2009|c|
|2009|d|
|2009|e|
|2009|g|
```

The goal would be to delete any classes which occure in the previous year, so the final data looks like this:

```
|year|class|
|---|----|
|2007|a|
|2007|b|
|2007|c|
|2007|d|
|2008|e|
|2008|f|
|2009|c|
|2009|d|
|2009|g|
```

I tried this code, I intendet to group the data and then delete all within group duplicates but it did not remove everything just a few rows.
Instead of duplicates() I also tried unique() which did not work.

```
d %>% group_by(class, Group = c(0, cumsum(diff(year) != 1))) %>%
  filter(!(duplicated(class, fromLast = TRUE)| duplicated(class))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-Group)
```

Is there maybe another R function which can look at group differences?
Thanks for any help

Edit: Thanks too all for your very helpfull answers!

Comment: 2009 d should also be in the output since there is no d in 2008.

Comment: Hi @Annabell. Does each class occur only once each year?

Comment: @Henrik Yes in my data each class can only occur once every year

Comment: Thanks @Annabell. A quick follow-up: if you have something like `df = data.table(year = 1:3, class = "a")`. On one hand we could argue that both year 2 and 3 should be removed right away (both have a registration in a previous year). On the other hand, if we approach this iteratively, once year 2 is removed, then year 3 would be OK. Which is your desired outcome? Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Left join DF to itself on class and a year difference of 1 and retain only those rows for which there is no such match.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.*
  from DF a
  left join DF b on b.class = a.class and b.year = a.year - 1
  where  b.year is null")
```

giving:

```
  year class
1 2007     a
2 2007     b
3 2007     c
4 2007     d
5 2008     e
6 2008     f
7 2009     c
8 2009     d
9 2009     g
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "|year|class|
|2007|a|
|2007|b|
|2007|c|
|2007|d|
|2008|a|
|2008|b|
|2008|e|
|2008|f|
|2009|c|
|2009|d|
|2009|e|
|2009|g|"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, sep = "|", header = TRUE)[2:3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some base R solution:

### `split` + `for` loop

```
dflst <- unname(split(df, df$year))
for (k in seq_along(dflst)[-1]) {
  dflst[[k]] <- subset(dflst[[k]], !class %in% dflst[[k - 1]]$class)
}
dfout <- do.call(rbind, dflst)
```

### `merge` + `subset` + `is.na`

```
dfout <- subset(merge(
  df,
  transform(
    df,
    yr = year + 1
  ),
  by.x = c("year", "class"),
  by.y = c("yr", "class"),
  all.x = TRUE
),
is.na(year.y),
select = -year.y
)
```

which gives

```
   year class
1  2007     a
2  2007     b
3  2007     c
4  2007     d
7  2008     e
8  2008     f
9  2009     c
10 2009     d
12 2009     g
```

## data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(year = c(2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L), class = c("a", "b",
"c", "d", "a", "b", "e", "f", "c", "d", "e", "g")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-12L))
```

Answer (score 2):

using `library(data.table)`

```
setDT(df)[, .(class = setdiff(class, df[year==y-1, class])), by=.(y=year)]

#       y class
# 1: 2007     a
# 2: 2007     b
# 3: 2007     c
# 4: 2007     d
# 5: 2008     e
# 6: 2008     f
# 7: 2009     c
# 8: 2009     d
# 9: 2009     g
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df=df[order(df$class,df$year),]
df$y_diff=c(0,diff(df$year))
df$c_lag=c("x",head(df$class,-1))

df[df$y_diff!=1 | df$class!=df$c_lag,1:2]

   year class
1  2007     a
2  2007     b
3  2007     c
9  2009     c
4  2007     d
10 2009     d
7  2008     e
8  2008     f
12 2009     g
```

Answer (score 2):

An analysis of all the current answer

```
df=structure(list(year = c(2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2008L, 2008L, 
                        2008L, 2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L), class = c("a", "b", 
                                                                             "c", "d", "a", "b", "e", "f", "c", "d", "e", "g")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                     -12L))

library(sqldf)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(microbenchmark)

groth = function() {
  sqldf("select a.*
  from df a
  left join df b on b.class = a.class and b.year = a.year - 1
  where  b.year is null")
}

thomas1 = function() {
  dflst <- unname(split(df, df$year))
  for (k in seq_along(dflst)[-1]) {
    dflst[[k]] <- subset(dflst[[k]], !class %in% dflst[[k - 1]]$class)
  }
  dfout <- do.call(rbind, dflst)
}

thomas2 = function() {
  dfout <- subset(merge(
    df,
    transform(
      df,
      yr = year + 1
    ),
    by.x = c("year", "class"),
    by.y = c("yr", "class"),
    all.x = TRUE
  ),
  is.na(year.y),
  select = -year.y
  )
}

dww = function() {
  setDT(df)[, .(class = setdiff(class, df[year==y-1, class])), by=.(y=year)]
}

user29 = function() {
  df=df[order(df$class,df$year),]
  df$y_diff=c(0,diff(df$year))
  df$c_lag=c("x",head(df$class,-1))
  df[df$y_diff!=1 | df$class!=df$c_lag,1:2]
}

anous = function() {
  df %>%
    group_by(class) %>%
    mutate(dup = n() > 1) %>%
    group_split() %>%
    map_dfr(~ if(unique(.x$dup) & (.x$year[2] - .x$year[1]) == 1) {
      .x %>% slice_head(n = 1)
    } else {
      .x
    }) %>%
    select(-dup) %>%
    arrange(year)
}
```

benchmark

```
set.seed(1)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  groth(), thomas1(), thomas2(), dww(), user29(), anous(), times=10)

Unit: microseconds
      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
   groth()  8864.702  9532.502 10885.691  9774.151 11628.401 14432.101    10
 thomas1()   792.801   836.001  1666.511  1024.651  1065.601  7921.401    10
 thomas2()  1758.700  2024.700  3172.011  2371.601  3348.701  8032.301    10
     dww()  3876.201  4280.400  4953.251  4383.701  5320.101  8807.501    10
  user29()   464.601   494.502  1249.081   542.951   643.300  7562.401    10
   anous() 10506.801 11091.602 12232.101 11424.801 12889.401 17279.201    10
```

with a much bigger dataframe, I had to remove thomas2 because it did not work

```
df=data.frame(
  "year"=sample(2000:2020,1e5,replace=T),
  "class"=sample(LETTERS[1:20],1e5,replace=T)
)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  groth(), thomas1(), dww(), user29(), anous(), times=10)

Unit: milliseconds
      expr       min          lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
   groth() 1217.9176 1270.225702 1290.86323 1305.06580 1322.3443 1341.0451    10
 thomas1()   13.6828   14.331401   17.94286   17.76540   21.2913   23.5265    10
     dww()   31.3091   36.660201   41.31367   40.27055   44.5629   54.6295    10
  user29()    7.8137    9.481402   11.97380   11.31740   14.2235   16.9593    10
   anous()   12.7733   13.266902   14.60760   13.50610   15.1067   19.9610    10
```

Comment: Thank you very much, always a great idea to benchmark various approaches. It's funny with much bigger data my solution fares much better.

Comment: I didn't bother trying to optimize for speed since clarity rather than speed is typically more important but the sqldf solution can be sped up by adding indexes.  This also applies to the data.table solution.

Answer (score 1):

#### General assumptions

Table is ordered by `Year`

#### Case one

For each group of records (grouped by `Year`) remove `Class` value if it has appeared in previous `Year`.

Solution

1. Transform the data, so for each `Year` in table, `Class` becomes a `list` of all `Class` values appeared during particular `Year` (`chop()`);
2. For each particular `Year` remove `Class` value (`setdiff`) if it has appeared during previous `Year` (`lag(Class)`);
3. Transform the `Class` from `list` of `list`s to atomic vector.

Code

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  chop(Class) %>% 
  mutate(Class = map2(Class, lag(Class), setdiff)) %>%
  unchop(Class)
```

Output

```
#  Year Class
#1 2007     a
#2 2007     b
#3 2007     c
#4 2007     d
#5 2008     e
#6 2008     f
#7 2009     c
#8 2009     d
#9 2009     g
```

#### Case two

This case is more interesting comparing to the previous one, because in order to solve it, one needs to compare current list of `Class` values, to all of the values of `Class` appeared during previous **years** (*sic!*).

Solution

1. Transform the data, so for each `Year` in table, `Class` becomes a `list` of all `Class` values appeared during particular `Year` (`chop()`);
2. Create list of `Class` values so each entry of the list contain the unique set of `Class` values appeared during particular `Year` and all the `Year`s before (`accumulate(Class, union)`);
3. For each particular `Year` remove `Class` value (`setdiff`) if it has appeared during previous `Year`s (`lag(...)`) as it has been calculated at step 2.
4. Transform the `Class` from `list` of `list`s to atomic vector.

Code

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  chop(Class) %>% 
  mutate(Class = map2(Class, lag(accumulate(Class, union)), setdiff)) %>%
  unchop(Class)
```

Output

```
#  Year Class
#1 2007     a
#2 2007     b
#3 2007     c
#4 2007     d
#5 2008     e
#6 2008     f
#7 2009     g
```

#### Data

I  have changed the names of the variables, capitalizing first letter. It is against the concept of *tidy data*, and it bothers me a lot. However, the fact that you do use name `class`, which is the name of a R's *primitive function* bothers me even more.

```
dat <- structure(
  list(
    Year = c(2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2009),
    Class = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "c", "d", "g")
  ),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-9L)
)
```

Comment: I really made a mistake with the desired output but your answer helped me a lot with the rest of my data!

Comment: Cool :) Consider it as an alternative solution. I will add the solution for your case latter it is simpler  than what I've provided already.

Comment: @Annabell I updated the answer, adding the explanation and solution for your particular case. Hope it might be useful / helpful for you in a future.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following `tidyverse` solution. I would like to thank @ThomasIsCoding for the data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  mutate(dup = n() > 1) %>%
  group_split() %>%
  map_dfr(~ if(unique(.x$dup) & (.x$year[2] - .x$year[1]) == 1) {
    .x %>% slice_head(n = 1)
    } else {
      .x
      }) %>%
  select(-dup) %>%
  arrange(year)

# A tibble: 9 x 2
   year class
  <int> <chr>
1  2007 a    
2  2007 b    
3  2007 c    
4  2007 d    
5  2008 e    
6  2008 f    
7  2009 c    
8  2009 d    
9  2009 g
```